# Unable to use CognitoIdentityServiceProvider from AWS SDK

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

I'm currently using `amazon-cognito-identity-js` and `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider`

and following this article https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

When calling `listUsersInGroup` function I'm initializing the `this.cognitoProvider` with `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`

Is there a way I can use the `CognitoIdentityServiceProvider` without specifying `accessKeyId` and `secretAccessKey`? I don't want to specify these keys since it contains sensitive information

**This works**

```
import { Config, CognitoIdentityCredentials, CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } from "aws-sdk";

export default class CognitoAuth {

   configure(config) {
     if (typeof config !== 'object' || Array.isArray(config)) {
       throw new Error('[CognitoAuth error] valid option object required')
     }
    
     this.userPool = new CognitoUserPool({
       UserPoolId: config.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
       ClientId: config.CLIENT_ID
     })

     Config.credentials = new CognitoIdentityCredentials({
       IdentityPoolId: config.IDENTITY_POOL_ID
     })

     this.cognitoProvider = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
       region: config.REGION,
       accessKeyId: config.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
       secretAccessKey: config.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
     });

    Config.region = config.REGION



    this.options = config

   }

   getUsersInGroup(context, cb) {
     var params = {
       GroupName: context.group,
       UserPoolId: this.options.IDENTITY_POOL_ID
     };

     this.cognitoProvider.listUsersInGroup(params, (err, data) => {
       if (err) console.log(err, err.stack)
       else cb(null, data.Users)
     })
   }
  
}
```

**This don't work**

```
this.cognitoProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ apiVersion: '2016-04-18' })
```

but I'm getting error `ConfigError: Missing region in config`

Answer (score 0):

As per your linked documentation page, calling the `listUsersInGroup` requires developer credentials, so these must be provided somehow.

If you look at [Setting credentials in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/setting-credentials-node.html), there are different ways to pass them, e.g., if running this function on a Lambda (or on an EC2 instance), it will use the Lambda (or EC2 instance) role permissions to call the method and credentials never have to be passed. Other options are using environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`/`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`) or shared credentials file.

However, your *immediate* problem seems to be regarding the region. While in the working block it is passed with `region: config.REGION,`, it is missing from the non working block. You can fix that by passing the `region` parameter when instantiating CognitoIdentityServiceProvider:

```js
this.cognitoProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({ 
  apiVersion: '2016-04-18', 
  region: 'us-east-1' // use your region
});
```

Comment: I checked the documentation. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html

It's possible to pass the credentials instead of AccessKeyId, but I'm still getting 
CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1